# Broadcast View (MTHKView) not Extending full screen

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming

Consider the following example

```
import AVFoundation
import HaishinKit
import VideoToolbox
import SwiftUI

struct TestStreamView: View {
    @State var rtmpStream: RTMPStream?
    var rtmpConnection = RTMPConnection()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            if let stream = rtmpStream {
                BroadcastView(stream: stream)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .onAppear {
            rtmpStream = RTMPStream(connection: rtmpConnection)
            guard let stream = rtmpStream else { return }
            stream.orientation = .portrait
            stream.captureSettings = [
                .sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080,
                .continuousAutofocus: true,
                .continuousExposure: true,
                .fps: 30
            ]
            stream.videoSettings = [
                .scalingMode: ScalingMode.cropSourceToCleanAperture,
                .width: 1080,
                .height: 1920,
                .bitrate: 5000000,
                .profileLevel: kVTProfileLevel_H264_Main_AutoLevel,
                .maxKeyFrameIntervalDuration: 2
            ]
            stream.audioSettings = [
                .bitrate: 128000 // Always use 128kbps
            ]

            stream.attachAudio(AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio))
            stream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: .front))
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am using a library called [HaishinKit](https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift) to set up my live stream feature.
I created a `UIViewRepresentable` for the `MTHKView` found in HaishinKit as follows

```
public struct BroadcastView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let stream: RTMPStream
    @State private var broadcastView: MTHKView?

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, RTMPStreamDelegate {
        var parent: BroadcastView

        init(_ parent: BroadcastView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // MARK: - RTMPStreamDelegate callbacks

        public func rtmpStreamDidClear(_ stream: RTMPStream) {}
        public func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didStatics connection: RTMPConnection) {}
        public func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didPublishInsufficientBW connection: RTMPConnection) {}
        public func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didPublishSufficientBW connection: RTMPConnection) {}

        @objc func focusGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            guard let broadcastView = parent.broadcastView else { return }
            if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
                let point = sender.location(in: broadcastView)
                let pointOfInterest = CGPoint(x: point.x / broadcastView.bounds.size.width, y: point.y / broadcastView.bounds.size.height)
                parent.stream.setPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest, exposure: pointOfInterest)
            }
        }
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MTHKView {
        let view = MTHKView(frame: .zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.attachStream(stream)
        stream.delegate = context.coordinator

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.broadcastView = view
        }
        let focusGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.focusGesture(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(focusGesture)
        return view
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: MTHKView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attachStream(stream)
    }
}
```

I'm facing two major issues with this setup here.

1. The MTHKView video capture doesn't extend to fullscreen (observe screenshot below with the black spacing)
2. I'm required to set the aspectRatio on the videoSettings property which doesn't seem the most ideal if using a different device.

Any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Adding `view.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill` fixes the problem